# GWT nocache.js status code 304

Tags: gwt, jboss7.x

I am writing GWT applicaiton. it was worked correctly. Then I put in `application.html`
`<body>` tag  something. then I remove it. After that applicaiton does'not renders. Empty page was rendered, and `application.nocache.js` status code is 304. 
I added `Filter` to reload newer versiton ev ery time. status code then is 200, but page does not renders anywey. 
In `devmode (mvn:gwt run)` page works correctly.

also there is an error in server mode. 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'visMode' of null`B4534804191C7F30C03D83F5ADA60018.cache.html:2781
SX B4534804191C7F30C03D83F5ADA60018.cache.html:2781
Fcb B4534804191C7F30C03D83F5ADA60018.cache.html:2140
..
(anonymous function) B4534804191C7F30C03D83F5ADA60018.cache.html:2313
gwtOnLoad B4534804191C7F30C03D83F5ADA60018.cache.html:2528
`B application.nocache.js:2`
phonebook1.onScriptLoad application.nocache.js:15
(anonymous function)`

Answer (score 1):

The application.nocache.js must not be in cache, the HTTP Code 304 say to the browser that the page was not modified.
You must in the Filter send to cache header for the file nocache.js:
http://seewah.blogspot.fr/2009/02/gwt-tips-2-nocachejs-getting-cached-in.html

Comment: My solution only worked after adding 'no-store' to the Cache-Control header.  I already had 'no-cache' but that wasn't enough.  I threw in 'must-revalidate' for good measure.  Note also that the url-pattern '*.nocache.js' works too for the filter config.